# merge [hbp] and [heated-bed] tags

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Dont [hbp](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hbp) and [heated-bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heated-bed) mean the same thing? Should one be synonim with the other?

Currently at the time of this post:

1. There are 11 questions tagged [hbp](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hbp)
2. Every single one of them have also [heated-bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heated-bed)
3. There are 12 questions tagged [heated-bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heated-bed)
4. Only [leeand00](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/797/what-kind-of-silicone-glue-should-i-use-to-attach-my-thermsistors) forgot to dual-tag his question... =P

Answer (score 2):

A synonym has been suggested already for the [hbp](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hbp) and [heated-bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heated-bed) tag. [hbp](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hbp) was added to a single post, and in order to create a synonym there needs to be at least 5 posts containing the similar tags. Now that the synonym has been suggested, most of those posts with dual tags can be reduced back to just [heated-bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heated-bed).

Currently, (03/28/2016), we do not have any moderators to make these tasks easier to manage.

If the synonym suggestion is not accepted, then external searches may be hindered to only display results for the term *heated-bed* as opposed to *heated-bed* **or** *hbp*. So, if you have a chance to properly address a synonym, definitely do so as it will only help bring more users to the site.

Comment: Why no moderators?

Comment: @Mindwin idk, I think the process got hung up. I believe StackExchange is currently in the process of selecting intermediate moderators until the community is built enough to conduct elections.

Comment: @tbm0115 90 days? That's a long time. I'll see if I can check something up. Either no one wants the job, or well... not of me to speculate.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Ironically, I just emailed someone with Stack this morning to get a status. I volunteered for moderation, and what I was told is what I mentioned in the comment above. However, it probably wouldn't hurt to try and invoke some action.

Comment: Yeah, 90 days is seriously pushing it. I'll see if I can get an eye on things