# Why are there both [heatbed] and [heated-bed] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I raised a question about heatbed/heated-bed support, [Steel versus MDF/Aluminium Y axis plate?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/3097/steel-versus-mdf-aluminium-y-axis-plate), and I noticed that there is not yet a heatbed-support tag, so I used [heatbed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heatbed), and also added [heated-bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heated-bed), just in case.

However, this raises the question why are there both? [heated-bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tags/heated-bed) has a short but sensible definition, whereas [heatbed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tags/heatbed) has no tag definition, so it is unclear the intended difference, if any, in their use.

After a quick search of Meta to see if this issue has already been raised, I, now, see that there is also the tag [hbp](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tags/hbp), see [merge [hbp] and [heated-bed] tags](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115/merge-hbp-and-heated-bed-tags).

For completeness, the respective use of each tag, to date, is as follows:

- [heatbed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heatbed) 5
- [heated-bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heated-bed) 34
- [hbp](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hbp) 11

So these are my questions:

- Should these tags be merged/deleted or left as is? It seems a little confusing, as it stands currently.
- Which is the preferred term, *heatbed*, or *heated bed*?
- Should I add the [hbp](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hbp) to my question?
- Should I remove the [heatbed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heatbed) tag from my question?
- With respect to my particular question, should I, also, have created a [heated-bed-support](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heated-bed-support), or a [heatbed-support](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heatbed-support) tag, or even a [hbp-support](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hbp-support) tag, so that it is more appropriately tagged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think they came about before anyone had the authority to suggest synonyms.

I went ahead and created a synonym for heatbed and heated-bed and merged the questions. I'll do the same for HBP. Thank you for bringing this up.